# No Hibernate Exception on the same insert of data

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Hibernate Newbie  here.  I am quite unsure why I am not getting any exception when I am executing below code.  On first attempt, this code creates the Book Entry on my Book Table.
    But my concern is that when I execute below code again, no error was pop out by Hibernate.
I was in fact expecting some sort of Violation of Primary Key Constraints as what I have bee doing in JDBC
code.

```
public class BookDao {
    public void createBook(Book bookObj) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
                .getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(bookObj);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}

public class BookDBStarter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book bookHF = new Book();
        bookHF.setIsbn("HF-12345");
        bookHF.setName("Head First HTML");
        bookHF.setPublishDate(new Date());

        BookDao daoBook = new BookDao();
        daoBook.createBook(bookHF);
    }
}
```

Is this normal hibernate way?  And how will I know if my insert is successful?  Any thoughts?

Comment: Where are the annotations? You should also show the Book.java code here for readers to better understand your question.

Comment: Which field is primary key and is there only one record after multiple runs?

Comment: @craftsman: the OP is using legacy Hibernate core, not the modern Hibernate EntityManager (JPA).

Comment: Sorry guys, I posted in haste without mentioning my table structure.  I was just excited with this hibernate thing after all those hardcore JDBC-only mapping.  Though I must say, I am having quite a hard time understanding this Hibernate thing.  Happy holidays everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that **booknumber** is the primary key, I hope you mention it as a primary key.Then in the createBook() method you started very well but you use  **session.saveOrUpdate(bookObj);**  statement. Because of this you are not getting any kind of key violation exception. While saving it is looking for the record if it is not present then it will save it in db but if it is present then it will update that record and hence you wont receive any kind of exception. Instead of that if you use **session.save(bookObj);** 
statement then it will definitely give you primary key exception if you define primary key properly.

Comment: Thanks.  I did look at the API and I notice the save and update method.  Doing the save twice generates the Violation of Primary Key that I am expecting. SaveOrUpdate saves the data if it is non-existing at the row and updates it when it is present.  I think I got it now.. =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish more info like the primary key of the table book. You will not get a Hibernate Exception when using saveOrUpdate unless you modify the primary key value of the already saved object.